# If the offer or demand for an ETF moves the ETF price far from the underlying net assets, does the fund management buy or sell underlying shares?

Tags: etf

I am reading contradictory  statements.

https://money.stackexchange.com/a/148855/5656 says yes:

> Only rarely - if the offer or demand for the ETF accumulates significantly over several days and moves the ETF price too far from the underlying net assets - will fund management buy or sell underlying shares.

https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/faqs says no:

> An index ETF only buys and sells stocks when its benchmark index does. Big investment moves—like when a company is removed from the index completely—happen very rarely.

If the offer or demand for the ETF accumulates significantly over several days and moves the ETF price too far from the underlying net assets, does the fund management buy or sell underlying shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorized Participants are market makers who have an incentive to keep ETFs close to NAV.

> If the price of an ETF share deviates from the value of its underlying
> securities, an AP may have an economic incentive to create or redeem
> ETF shares.

[Policy Spotlight: Authorized Participants](https://www.blackrock.com/corporate/literature/whitepaper/policy-spotlight-authorized-participants-december-2020.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: Thanks!  [Does such a creation or the redemption of ETF shares by an Authorized Participant cause any capital gain distributions to the individual investors?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/148867/5656)

Comment: Creation/redemption is an in-kind transaction which is tax exempt.