# Does the creation/redemption of ETF shares by an AP when the ETF price deviated too much from its underlying securities cause cap gain distributions?

Tags: etf, capital-gain, authorized-participant

From [Policy Spotlight: Authorized Participants](https://www.blackrock.com/corporate/literature/whitepaper/policy-spotlight-authorized-participants-december-2020.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/etf-authorized-participants-december-2020)), which [Orange Coast- reinstate Monica](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/63252/orange-coast-reinstate-monica) [referred](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/148863/5656) me to:

> If the price of an ETF share deviates from the value of its underlying securities, an AP may have an economic incentive to create or redeem ETF shares.

Which they illustrate with this flowchart:

[image]

Does such a creation or the redemption of ETF shares by an Authorized Participant when the price of the ETF share deviates from the value of its underlying securities cause any capital gain distributions to the retail investors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation/redemption process is usually an in-kind transaction - the exchange of securities for ETF shares (and vice versa) is tax exempt.  Therefore, the fund doesn't have to sell securities to generate cash and avoids generating taxable gains for non-redeeming shareholders.

This redemption mechanism can also remove capital gains and permit non-redeeming shareholders to defer taxes on their gains.

Comment: Thanks!  [Why does the redemption of ETF shares by an Authorized Participant when the ETF price deviated too much from its underlying securities may permit non-redeeming shareholders to defer taxes on their gains?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/148900/5656)

Comment: I don't know the specifics.  [Read this article](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/110315/do-etfs-pay-capital-gains.asp#:~:text=When%20ETFs%20are%20simply%20bought%20and%20sold%2C%20there,do%20not%20expose%20their%20shareholders%20to%20capital%20gains.) Perhaps it will help. "Through authorized participants, ETFs can create or redeem "creation units," which are blocks of assets that represent an ETF's securities exposure on a smaller scale. "

Comment: cont.  "By doing so, ETFs typically do not expose their shareholders to capital gains. Occasionally, an ETF may incur a capital gain due to some special circumstances, where it has to drastically rebalance its portfolio due to substantial changes in the underlying benchmark. Also, leveraged, inverse, and emerging market ETFs typically cannot use in-kind delivery of securities to create or redeem shares. This triggers capital gains more often for these kinds of ETFs when compared to index ETFs."